# How do I add the latest jQuery-UI library to an MVC4 project?

Tags: .net, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

Assuming that I create a new internet application in MVC4 using the default template, how do I add the the latest jquery ui package to it? I've downloaded the zip file that you get from the site after you choose a theme, but for the life of me, I can't get it to work. I've copied the js files to the scripts folder and the redmond theme to the content/themes folder. I've tried referencing files in the view, I've tried referencing them in the layout. The example I am trying to use to test it is the Tabs function.

I'm just going to assume that I'm screwing this up completely. Could someone throw me a bone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok nuget was definitely at least half of the battle, but what I was failing to find on the internet, I just found a moment ago:

In the layout page, I needed to add the following to the body section, before the render section for scripts

```
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

And then in the view itself, add the script call to the scripts SECTION at the BOTTOM of the view:

```
@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#tabs').tabs();
        });
    </script>
}
```

As far as the theme goes, I just referenced the style sheet in the layout view

Answer (score 1):

Use nuget. Right click your project, thant manage nuget packages. Find it and instalk

Comment: @Sinaesthetic is looking for jQueryUI with the Redmond theme. NuGet only installs the base theme.